# Add class to relative layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Actually I had made the TableMainLayout that shows scrollable Table and I am viewing it using an result_activity-:

in the result

```
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(new TableMainLayout(this));
        }
```

Now I want to add this table to the result_activity.xml that has some text and button then what should I do-:

My activity_result.xml is as follows -:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.pranav.tegate.result"
        android:background="#010101"
        android:id="@+id/myResult">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hari Bol"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/a"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="33dp" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

I also tried some of the things -:

```
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

            TableMainLayout addTable = new TableMainLayout(this);
            addTable.setId(1);

            relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.myResult);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) relativeLayout.getLayoutParams();


            relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW , addTable.getId());
            relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(relativeParams);

            relativeLayout.addView(addTable);
        }
```

But this is not working-: I am getting the following error
Caused by:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams      cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
```

how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

The `LayoutParams` object refers also to the parent's `View`. In your case the `RelativeLayout` is the root, and it gets inflated into `android.R.id.content` which is a `FrameLayout`, hence the `ClassCastException`. What you want to achieve is probably possible if you wrap your `RelativeLayout`, into another `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(relativeParams);
```

And change this line:

```
relativeLayout.addView(addTable, relativeParams);
```

And, if I correctly understand what you're trying to do, you probably want to change the `addRule()` call, as well:

```
relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.textView3);
```

A View's `LayoutParams` define how that View is laid out in its parent View. You're getting a `ClassCastException` because `relativeLayout` is actually in a `FrameLayout` - the Activity's `content` ViewGroup - and it should therefore have `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`. To specify a child View's `LayoutParams` when adding it to a ViewGroup, you can pass it as the second argument in the `addView()`, as shown above.